# I am trying display the pause icon while playing the sound and then display the play icon when the sound finish playing

Tags: java, android

here I'm trying to show the pause icon when media is playing and I want to automatically change to play icon after the media finish playing. The first time whenever I click on the play icon it would change to pause icon but it wouldn't change back to play icon after the media finish playing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton playBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.evumm);

        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playicon);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (sound.isPlaying()) {
                    sound.pause();
                    playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playicon);
                } else {

                    sound.start();
                    playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

XML code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="develop.kokoson.playorstopapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play or Pause !"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/playicon"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `OnCompletionListener` in MediaPlayer to do this. Just add a listener that sets the button icon back to the play icon when the sound is complete.

```
sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playicon);
    }
});
```

Comment: I implemented on two ImageButtons playing different sounds. It turns out that the first ImageButton wouldn't change back to play icon after sound finish playing but the second works fine and the ImageButton changes to play icon after sound finish playing. Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: Sure. The best approach here would be to mark this answer as accepted and add a new question with your new code though.